# Does 'Jet Impingement Cooling' always cool?

Tags: heat-transfer, cooling, convection, jet

I understand that by using jet impingement cooling, we can achieve a high convective heat transfer rate, but there is also a stagnation region where the kinetic energy of the jet will be converted to heat and so create a region of higher temperature. So does the Jet impingement 'cooling' always cool, OR is there a condition that it will only cool as long as the surface temperature is greater than the stagnation temperature of the jet?

Comment: There are always implicit conditions. For example you may not be able to cool something that is already very cold.

Comment: A properly designed cooler will cool.  A 1000 kph air jet will probably make things get hot in certain conditions. Edge conditions exist.